# CSS Selector in soup.select() returns null

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm learning web scraping and want to fetch data from webpage that matches the css i am passing in `soup.select("css locators")`. When i inspect the css locators in webpage, it highlights the correct elements but when i use the same in the `soup.select()` method it returns none or 0.

1. I'm retrieving a data from a website: https://www.prokabaddi.com/teams/bengaluru-bulls-profile-1
2. Css selector used to fetch data from above website: `.si-section-header > span.si-title`
3. with the above css when i inspect the webpage in browser its works fine but when i use the same in the `soup.select(".si-section-header > span.si-title")` method it returns none or 0

```
# code sample 
import requests 
import bs4 

URL = "https://www.prokabaddi.com/teams/bengaluru-bulls-profile-1"
r = requests.get(URL) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser') 
a = soup.select('.si-section-header > span.si-title')
Print(a)
```

I expect the output to return the values the CSS selectors highlights. In this case the CSS highlights 3 values so i expect it to print all the three values when i execute the above code.

Comment: I don't see any `si-section-header` on that page.

Comment: Parts of that page are generated by javascript after the page is loaded. `BeautifulSoup` will not see that. Try `print(r.content)` to see what `BeautifulSoup` actually gets.

Answer (score 2):

Large amounts of content are dynamically added and not caught in your initial request. The elements you are looking at are part of a template pulled from another resource. You can find it in the network tab when refreshing the page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.prokabaddi.com/static-assets/kabaddi/views/kwl-team-stats-partial.html?v=1.064')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print([i.text for i in soup.select('.si-title')])
```

Comment: Excellent stuff.I haven't noticed.

Comment: @KunduK I haven't looked closely enough but I am wondering if there is a case change by js as you need a case insensitive search to locate as some casing is different.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data you want, much of this data is returned in JSON.

```
import requests

j = requests.get("https://www.prokabaddi.com/sifeeds/kabaddi/live/json/multisport_cache_25_3_pkl_0530_en_team_1.json").json()

for match in j['matches']:
    print(match)
```

Other URLs that may have the data you want include:

https://www.prokabaddi.com/sifeeds/kabaddi/static/json/1_team.json

https://www.prokabaddi.com/sifeeds/kabaddi/live/json/multisport_cache_25_3_0_0530_en_4.json

You can see them all by opening developer tools selecting the networks tab then XHR and refreshing the page

Comment: thanks a ton for the answer, this is so simple and it worked like a charm. Thanks again.